# 3G modem connect success, but minicom will block, how can i get in command mode?

Tags: linux

minicom:

```
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","3gnet"
OK
ATDT*99#
CONNECT
```

At this time minicom will block. But i want to get exec other command. how can i do it?

my device:

```
ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem
```

Comment: Off-topic, SO is for programming questions. Perhaps [Superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

as root:

```
minicom -s
```

configure your serial port. The when at the mincom menu that provides `Exit` or `Exit Minicom`, choose `Exit` and you will be dumped to terminal mode where you can communicate with your modem via the `AT Command set`.